# Creating stronger self signed certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl

I've installed the calomel addon in Firefox, which gives information about the quality of an SSL certificate. I have created a self signed certificate, which scores full point on PFS and the Bulk Cipher, but not on the rest. How can I create a better certificate on Debian?

[image: Calomel validation for Google certificate]
[image: Calomel validation for self signed certificate]

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing things. There are two separate issues here:

- Your certificate was made using a 1024 bit key. This is easily rectified: `openssl genrsa -des3 -out privkey.pem 2048` creates a 2048 bit key, the rest of the procedure remains the same.
- Your webserver's encryption configuration is sub-standard: You have to move ciphers with Elliptic-Curve DH key exchange to the front of your preferred cipher list. You should push ciphers only included for backwards-compatibility to the back.

My Apache configuration currently looks like this:

```
SSLProtocol +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1
SSLCompression off
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDH-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:ECDH-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:RC4-SHA"
```

This gives a full grade on [Qualys SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).

Please note that Apache 2.2 *does not* support Elliptic-Curve cryptography.